# Clearing Viewstate of Dynamically Created Controls to Add New Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, viewstate, dynamically-generated

I currently have a static drop down list whose items get bound from a database on Page Load. Based on the selection in this drop down list I am dynamically generating a set of controls in a table with the ID's "CustomControl1", "CustomControl2", etc. What I need to do is with each selection in the drop down list there is a unique set of controls of different control types, but they all have the same ID (based on the order they are generated). So when I try generating a new set of controls I am getting this error:

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

So in the page load I have two methods, one that generates the control based on an xml and another that creates validation controls like so:

```
        if (xml != "" && externalProperties.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            LoadExternalProperties(xml);
            ValidateExternalProperties(xml);
        }
```

When I make my initial selection, I am able to generate the controls properly, when I make a secondary selection the controls cannot be generated because the viewstates don't match up for the different control types.

So I assume that what I need to do is clear the viewstate. I have tried the following:

Setting the viewstate to null(Attempted outside of Page_Init and In):

```
ViewState["CustomControl1"] = null;
```

Clearing the table of the rows:

```
externalProperties.Rows.Clear();
```

Clearing the table of the controls:

```
externalProperties.Controls.Clear();
```

Toggling EnableViewState before and after loading controls:

```
externalProperties.EnableViewState = false;
LoadExternalProperties(xml);
externalProperties.EnableViewState = true;
```

- I only need to clear the viewstate when the selected index of the drop down list changes. This is because in the following step(using a wizard), I am retrieving the values and using them for some other purposes.

I am currently tracking the previous selected index in order to figure out when I have to clear the viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

You should **EnableViewState = false** of the dropdownlist control.

Comment: the viewstate for the dropdownlist needs to be retained. It's the viewstate of the controls that I dynamically generate based on the dropdownlist value that I need to clear.